# Disable different Inputs based on Option selected from a <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a contact us form, which should concede of multiple Text Inputs, A Text area & a Submit button. Above this form should be a drop down selection with three options in this example I've used 'Select an Option','Option 1' & 'Option2'.

I'm trying to get it so that all of the elements on the form are disabled unless 'Option 1' is selected. So if either of the other 2 are selected, the form should not be accessible by the user.

Currently I've managed to figure out how to disable one input but the other one doesn't seem to work the same way. What is the reason behind this? Also how can I get it to disable the other elements?

```js
function checkOption(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    input.disabled = obj.value == "A";
}
```

```html
<p>Contact Us Form </P>

<select id="menu" onChange="checkOption(this)">
    <option value="A">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="B">Option 1</option>
    <option value="A">Option 2</option>
</select>

<br>
<p> First Name </p>
<input type="text" id="input" disabled>

<p> Second Name </p>
<input type="text" id="input" disabled>

<p>Enquiry</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols"50" id="textarea">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an modo mucius eum,
sanctus concludaturque qui no. Stet esse intellegat no eam,
nonumes eligendi disputationi ad usu.
</textarea>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: You can't use the same id `id="input"` multiple times :)

Comment: You are having multiple lements with the same id....<input type="text" id="input" disabled> and <input type="text" id="input" disabled>. try to use different ids and retest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : first of all don't use same id for multiple input (elements), use class or name attribute instead of id.
Get all elements by name and then disable-

```js
function checkOption(obj) {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("input");
    for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
     input[i].disabled = !(obj.value == "B")
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Contact Us Form </P>

<select id="menu" onChange="checkOption(this)">
    <option value="A">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="B">Option 1</option>
    <option value="A">Option 2</option>
</select>

<br>
<p> First Name </p>
<input type="text" name="input" disabled>

<p> Second Name </p>
<input type="text" name="input" disabled>

<p>Enquiry</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols"50" id="textarea" name="input" disabled>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an modo mucius eum,
sanctus concludaturque qui no. Stet esse intellegat no eam,
nonumes eligendi disputationi ad usu.
</textarea>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="input" disabled>
```

Comment: That works great! Now I've added the name="input" to the rest of the elements but they don't seem to be disabled upon loading unlike the two text inputs. Why is this?

Comment: can you pls share your html with rest of the inputs for which you set name="input"?

Comment: <textarea name="input" rows="4" cols"50" id="textarea">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an modo mucius eum,
sanctus concludaturque qui no. Stet esse intellegat no eam,
nonumes eligendi disputationi ad usu.
</textarea>

<br>
<input name="input" type="submit" value="Submit" >

Comment: You need to add `disabled` property to the other input elements, so that you can set true / false to the property. I have edited this in my answer, please check.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

First Remove duplicate IDs.

than You can do like this

```
 function checkOption(obj) {
        if(obj.value!="Option_1"){

         $("#formId:input").prop("disabled", true);

        }else{

         $("#formId:input").prop("disabled", false);
        }

    }
```